# Undo/redo in paint app in opengl

Tags: ios5, opengl-es

I am developing paint application in iOS using openGL. Each time i switch the page I save drawing as a .png.When I come back I draw that saved image using texture by making it as power of 2. Now at the time of undo/Redo  I clear whole framebuffer and Redraw all (.png+remaining stuff).In this case my performance decrease as I draw each time a large texture image.

Is there any way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you don't save anything to permanent storage unless the application is terminated.

Also, use texture no larger that 1024 x 1024.

Moreover, avoid using .png if you are not taking advantage of the transparency. .jpg are way smaller in size.

That should improve your performance dramatically.

Comment: I am using texture of size 1024 x 1024.I need transparency as well.So what is the solution.Where should I save those images in place of permanent storage.I think storage is not an issue.Because at the time of undo/redo I directly load texture for that image not image from permanent storage.

Comment: If you say "I directly load texture for that image", that tells me you are reading your image from your hard drive again. You should only do that once on, on the start up of your app. Then you should keep your image alive on the RAM memory. Moreover, reading from a hard drive is slow, but reading from RAM is the fastest way.